# How to scrape post div table content on VBA?

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am new to web-scraping. I am trying to get data from O-net online. To be specific, I would like to draw the median wages and employment stats for a few dozens selected jobs. For example:
https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/13-2041.00

[O-net content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPFAV.png)

[Upon inspection, the html looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWzkh.png)

Below is my code though it does not work.

```
Sub scrape()
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/13-2041.00"
    .Visible = False
End With
Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementByID("wrapper_WagesEmployment").getelementbytagname("table")(0)

Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(3).innerHTML
appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing
Range("A1").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to paste the entire `innerHTML` into cell A1? Not any specific content (i.e. Median Wages - "$36.05 hourly, $74,970 annual" in your URL)

Comment: I only want to put "$36.05 hourly, $74,970 annual" into the cell. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to help you identify which variable are not declared properly.
2. You spelled `getelementbytagname` method wrong, it's `getElementsByTagName`.

Try the below code:

```
Private Sub scrape()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    
    With appIE
        .navigate "https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/13-2041.00"
        .Visible = False
    
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
    
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Set ieDoc = appIE.Document
    
    Dim allRowOfData As Object
    Set allRowOfData = ieDoc.getElementById("wrapper_WagesEmployment").getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
        
    Dim medianWageValue As String
    medianWageValue = allRowOfData.getElementsByClassName("report2")(0).innerText
    
    Range("A1").Value = medianWageValue 'Fully qualify your range referece e.g. Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    
    Set ieDoc = Nothing
    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Alternative - You can do the same using XMLHTTP that doesn't require you to open IE and most of the time, faster (You will need to add `Microsoft HTML Object Library` in your reference):

```
Private Sub ScrapeByXMLHTTP()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    With xmlhttp
        .Open "GET", "https://www.onetonline.org/link/summary/13-2041.00"
        .send
        
        Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Set htmlDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = htmlDoc.getElementById("wrapper_WagesEmployment").getElementsByTagName("table")(0).outerHTML
    
    Dim medianWageValue As String
    medianWageValue = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("report2")(0).innerText
    Set htmlDoc = nothing

    Range("A1").Value = medianWageValue 'Fully qualify your range referece e.g. Sheet1.Range("A1").Value        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond, it works perfectly fine. Wish you a nice day ahead.